# How to fix the problem of animation starting only after the full page loads?

Tags: wordpress, animate.css, wow.js

I would like to animate a phrase in a wordpress site with a help from animate.css and wow.js. When I reload a page the phrase I would like to animate appears like a ordinary text and only after that the animation starts to happen. I tried to change the order of scripts but still it doesn't work the way it supposed to.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
add_action('wp_footer', 'theme_scripts');

 function theme_styles() {
       wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri()); 
       wp_enqueue_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/animate.css');       
 }
 function theme_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_script('wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/wow.min.js');
       wp_enqueue_script('animate_init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/animate-init.js');
}
```

Comment: How are you initializing the animation?  Is it within a DOM Ready event, such as jQuery?  In this case your function may not run until the dom is ready/page loads.  Which you should generally do as good practice anyways, but may solve your issue if that's the case.

Comment: @DubVader It's in animate-init.js I have this line new WOW().init();

Comment: @DubVader Nothing changes if I write document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  new WOW().init()
  });

Comment: Why don't you hide the text by default, then initialize your WOW, then right after that, show the text.

Answer (score 0):

You missing one thing I suppose: using **[the right action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)** for calling these functions, in this case you need wp_enqueue_scripts.

For including properly CSS/JS, i.e you can try this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_and_css' );
function my_scripts_and_css(){
theme_styles();
theme_scripts();
}
```

You can also install a plugin for easy inserting JS code snippets manually, i.e [this](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/).

Comment: I've updated a question. My scripts are visible in the console and animation works but it works only after the text I target to animate appears for a second without any animation.